# Angular - Jasmine - Karma - Highcharts Error #16

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, jasmine, karma-runner

In `karma.conf.js` in files I include:
`'bower_components/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js'`

In my unit tests, I am testing a series of Highchart directives
When I run my tests with karma I get:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16
  at undefined
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16
  at undefined
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 84 of 85 ERROR (1.136 secs / 1.628 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

That error means that window.Highcharts was initialized more than once and Highcharts throws an exception.

How can I load the file in Karma once and not for every test?

Here are the full list of files in the Karma config:

`files: [
      'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      'bower_components/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.angular.js',
      'bower_components/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js',
      'bower_components/angular-md5/angular-md5.js',
      'bower_components/lodash/lodash.js',
      'bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js',
      'bower_components/moment/moment.js',
      'bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js',
      'bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js',
      'bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.js',
      'bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js',
      'bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js',
      'bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js',
      'bower_components/pdf-viewer/viewer.js',
      'bower_components/javascript-detect-element-resize/detect-element-resize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-gridster/src/angular-gridster.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      "app/scripts/**/*.js",
      "bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js",
      "bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js",
      "bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js",
      "bower_components/pdf-viewer/viewer.js",
      "app/views/**/*.html",
      "test/mock/**/*.js",
      "test/spec/controllers/*.js",
      "test/spec/filters/*.js",
      "test/spec/services/*.js",
      "test/spec/directives/**/*.js",
      "test/spec/app.js",
    ],`

Comment: I'm presuming you haven't listed it twice in the files included by putting it: files: ['/src/'bower_components/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js', 'src/**/*.js']? (Depending on how you have your directories arranged.)

Comment: You mention you load `highcharts-ng.js` but that's just the Angular wrapper, not Highcharts itself. It might be best if you just show the `files` array from `karma.conf.js`

Comment: @Phil I think you're mistaken, the only reference to highcharts in my index.html is `<script src="bower_components/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js"></script>` so I think that is what brings highcharts in

Comment: So Karma and Jasmine re-use the same DOM and then re-load the files on every test run?

Comment: Nevermind @Phil there is a lazy load of HighCharts that I missed.

Comment: @TutanRamen So, the problem is solved?

Comment: Ha no not really...I switched from Chrome to Firefox to run my karma tests and it went away. Still happens when using Chrome :-/